# Changing Color in JAVA GUI(Eclipse) for Game of Life

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

The following is the code for Conway's Game of Life, although the program runs perfectly

The GUI prints blocks in Black and White. How do I change the code for  it to print out Red(Dead) and Green(Alive ) instead

```
public class GameofLife {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int frameSize = 360;
    public static String title = "Game Of Life";

    public Random r = new Random();
    public int gridSize = 100;
    public double generationSpeed = 20.0;

    public BufferedImage image;
    public int[] pixels;

    public boolean[] cGrid;
    public boolean[] pGrid;

    public GameofLife() {
        Dimension d = new Dimension(frameSize, frameSize);
        setMinimumSize(d);
        setMaximumSize(d);
        setPreferredSize(d);

        image = new BufferedImage(gridSize, gridSize, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    }

    public void start() {
        cGrid = new boolean[pixels.length];
        pGrid = new boolean[pixels.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < cGrid.length; i++)
        cGrid[i] = r.nextInt(100) / 100.0 > 0.8 ? true: false;

        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        double frameCut = 1000000000.0 / generationSpeed;

        long currentTime = System.nanoTime();;
        long previouseTime = currentTime;
        long passedTime = 0;

        double unprocessedTime = 0.0;

        long frameCounter = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int generations = 1;

        while (true) {
            previouseTime = currentTime;
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            passedTime = currentTime - previouseTime;

            unprocessedTime += passedTime;

            if (unprocessedTime > frameCut) {
                unprocessedTime = 0;
                update();
                generations++;
            }

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - frameCounter >= 1000) {
                frameCounter = System.currentTimeMillis();

            }

            render();
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
        pGrid[i] = cGrid[i];

        for (int y = 0; y < gridSize; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++) {
                int res = 0;

                int xx0 = x - 1;
                int yy0 = y - 1;
                int xx1 = x + 1;
                int yy1 = y + 1;

                if (x != 0) res += pGrid[xx0 + gridSize * y] ? 1 : 0;
                if (y != 0) res += pGrid[x + gridSize * yy0] ? 1 : 0;
                if (x != gridSize - 1) res += pGrid[xx1 + gridSize * y] ? 1 : 0;
                if (y != gridSize - 1) res += pGrid[x + gridSize * yy1] ? 1 : 0;
                if (x != 0 && y != 0) res += pGrid[xx0 + gridSize * yy0] ? 1 : 0;
                if (x != 0 && y != gridSize - 1) res += pGrid[xx0 + gridSize * yy1] ? 1 : 0;
                if (x != gridSize - 1 && y != 0) res += pGrid[xx1 + gridSize * yy0] ? 1 : 0;
                if (x != gridSize - 1 && y != gridSize - 1) res += pGrid[xx1 + gridSize * yy1] ? 1 : 0;

                if (! (pGrid[x + gridSize * y] && (res == 3 || res == 2))) cGrid[x + gridSize * y] = false;
                if (!pGrid[x + gridSize * y] && res == 3) cGrid[x + gridSize * y] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
        pixels[i] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
        pixels[i] = cGrid[i] ? 0xffffff: 0;

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, frameSize, frameSize, null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        GameofLife gol = new GameofLife();
        frame.add(gol);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        gol.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you, or rather, have you tried, spotting the colors?

Comment: Whose code is this? Where did you find it?

Comment: Not sure, but I totally just drew Abe Lincoln's head messing around with some of these variables.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sample code

Comment: @Justas Tried, couldnt find anything

Answer (score 0):

The color is set in this code section

```
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
    pixels[i] = cGrid[i] ? 0xffffff : 0;
```

If you want to set different off/on colors, you can make a simple adaption

```
int off = Color.red.getRGB();
int on = Color.green.getRGB();

for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
    pixels[i] = cGrid[i] ? on : off;
```